# How to evaluate on both train and validation set in keras?

Tags: keras

```python
class RocAucEvaluation(Callback):
    def __init__(self,  validation_data=(), interval=1):
        super(Callback, self).__init__()
        self.interval = interval
        self.X_val, self.y_val = validation_data
    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        if epoch % self.interval == 0:
            y_pred = self.model.predict(self.X_val, verbose=0)
            score = roc_auc_score(self.y_val, y_pred)
            print("\n ROC-AUC - epoch: %d -  score: %.6f \n" % (epoch+1, score))

RocAuc = RocAucEvaluation(validation_data=(validate_x, validate_y), interval=1)
model.fit(train_x, train_y, batch_size=20000, epochs=3, verbose=1, callbacks=[RocAuc],class_weight={0:0.0025,1:0.9985},\
         validation_data=(validate_x, validate_y))
```

My code can evaluate AUC every epoch on validation set. How can I modify the code to make it evaluate on both train and validate set at the same time ?

Comment: what is self.x_val is that not the training set?

Comment: What about using two `RocAucEvaluation` callbacks, one with `validation_data=(train_x, train_y)` and the other with `validation_data=(validate_x, validate_y)`?